# Can you get contacts off a broken android phone?

Tags: contacts, recovery-mode, broken-screen

I in a car wreck and my hip completely smashed my phone, it turns only turns on about half the time when  i plug it in and the screen is too shattered for touch to work so not really worth spending that much to fix it. is there any way to transfer a few contacts to my computer without expensive recovery software? They wernt on my SIM card, I'm job hunting and DESPERATELY need my work references and no possible clue what old email i had the phone synced with.
 Any help very much appreciated!

Comment: If you had synchronization enabled shouldn't all contacts be visible in your `gmail` account?

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! Please take a look at our [broken-screen tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/broken-screen/info) for some first aid and helpful links. Recovering data from a device with a broken screen happens to be a question asked regularly, so we set up some information on this topic there. Having checked that, please come back here and let us know if you were able to solve your issue – or if you're stuck, what you've tried and what went wrong. Fingers crossed, good luck to you (including the "health part")!